# Flutter Bloc Design - Inform pages about changes

Tags: flutter, bloc

is there a best practice for this? (Im using this Todo example since its easier to explain my problem here)

1. TodoOverviewPage (Shows all todos)
2. TodoAddPage (Page to add todos)

Each page has an own Bloc.

Steps:

1. From the TodoOverviewPage I navigate wuth pushNamed to TodoAddPage.
2. In TodoAddPage I add several Todos.
3. Using the Navigation Back Button to go back to TodoOverviewPage

Question: How should I inform TodoOverviewPage that there are new Todos?

My approaches which Im not sure if this is the right way.
Solutions:

1. Overwriting the Back Button in TodoAddPage. To add a "refresh=true" property.
2. Adding the Bloc from TodoOverviewPage to TodoAddPage. And setting the State to something that the TodoOverviewPage will reload todos after building.

Thank you for reading.

EDIT1:

- Added my temporary solution till I find something which satisfies me more.

Comment: Do you got my point?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by different way

1. InheritedWidget
2. ValueCallback in TodoAddPage

For Example:

```
class Item {
   String reference;

   Item(this.reference);
}

class _MyInherited extends InheritedWidget {
  _MyInherited({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
    @required this.data,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final MyInheritedWidgetState data;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_MyInherited oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class MyInheritedWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyInheritedWidget({
    Key key,
    this.child,
  }): super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  MyInheritedWidgetState createState() => new MyInheritedWidgetState();

  static MyInheritedWidgetState of(BuildContext context){
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_MyInherited) as _MyInherited).data;
  }
}

class MyInheritedWidgetState extends State<MyInheritedWidget>{
  /// List of Items
  List<Item> _items = <Item>[];

  /// Getter (number of items)
  int get itemsCount => _items.length;

  /// Helper method to add an Item
  void addItem(String reference){
    setState((){
      _items.add(new Item(reference));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new _MyInherited(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class MyTree extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTreeState createState() => new _MyTreeState();
}

class _MyTreeState extends State<MyTree> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MyInheritedWidget(
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new WidgetA(),
            new Container(
              child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  new WidgetB(),
                  new WidgetC(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyInheritedWidgetState state = MyInheritedWidget.of(context);
    return new Container(
      child: new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text('Add Item'),
        onPressed: () {
          state.addItem('new item');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyInheritedWidgetState state = MyInheritedWidget.of(context);
    return new Text('${state.itemsCount}');
  }
}

class WidgetC extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text('I am Widget C');
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess your 2nd way is like my 1st approach. About your 1st way, I dont have a parent-child relationship between those two widget pages.

Comment: Added my temporary solution till I find something better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55336464/2704566

Comment: Dont forget to give credits to "Didier" ^^ https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/06/widget---state---context---inheritedwidget/

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

Each (root) Page which has a Bloc now always reloads when build.

The Bloc takes care for caching.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageBloc pBloc = BlocProvider.of<PageBloc >(context);
    bool isNewBuild = true;

    return Scaffold(
    ...
        body: BlocBuilder<PageBlocEvent, PageBlocState>(
            if (isNewBuild) {
                pBloc.dispatch(PageBlocEvent(PageBlocEventType.GETALL));
                isNewBuild = false;
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else {
                // Draw data
                ...
    ...
}
```